# Can't install VMware tools (Mac OS 10.7)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to install VMware tools on the Guest OS (OS inside VMware), which is Mac OS 10.7. Windows hosts VMware which hosts Mac OS.

I just eject the disk and press "install VMware tools". Basically that's all I do.  I get an error "You cannot install VMware Tools in this location".

[image: error pic]

If I don't eject the disk, I get the message:

> This operation cannot proceed because your Mac OS guest is using the CD/DVD. Dismiss this message, eject the disk from inside the guest, and retry this operation.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I just eject the disk and press "install VMware tools". Basically that's all what I do

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but are you sure you're supposed to eject the disk before installing?  If it needs to copy content from the disk to install, the error message may reflect an inability to install at all rather than a problem with the location.

Comment: Otherwise i get message "This operation cannot proceed because your Mac OS guest is using the CD/DVD. Dismiss this message, eject the disk from inside the guest, and retry this operation"

Comment: Can I confirm, whether you are trying to install the VMWare Tools on the Guest OS (the OS that is running as a virtual machine), or the Host OS (the OS that runs the VM software)? As the VMWare Tools is for the Guest OS.

Comment: I'm trying to install it on the Guest OS(OS inside VMware). Windows hosts VMware which hosts Mac OS

Comment: Running Mac OS on non-Apple hardware is unsupported and violates the EULA.  Unfortunately, "Hackintosh" questions are off-topic.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion
And i can install it using vm. What's a problem?

Comment: The problem is Apple's EULA which does not permit installing OS X/macOS on anything other than Apple hardware. VMWare already knows this, which is why there are no tools.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: sry, the problem is just lack of $1.4k for real mac for developing and self-fulfillment

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy Hackintosh questions are not necessarily off-topic, but they do tend to fall into one of a few categories that make them unanswerable. @Tetsujin

Comment: @music2myear - Well, there's still the oft-revisited, but still admin-stamped https://meta.superuser.com/a/1473/347380 answer. But, as you say, it's often 'unsupported hardware with no drivers' that puts the end to it.... which is probably the case here. On the other hand, how much traction would a request for a Windows keygen get on here - that's only a civil contract too...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just installed 10.12 instead of 10.7
It seems that VMware Tools can not be installed alongside Mac OS 10.7, but on Sierra(10.12) everything is OK